# HTML Email Showing Gap Between Image Slices

Tags: html, css, email

My HTML email is showing a slight, one pixel gap between images when viewed in the Gmail app.

How can I get rid of this gap so my image slices look like one, fluid image?

I have tried display: block on the images, padding: 0 and margin: 0 but I'm still getting that gap.

Here is my HTML:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 650px !important; padding: 0 !important;">
    <tr style="padding: 0 !important;">
        <td style="padding: 0 !important; line-height: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
            <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_parent" style="display: block !important;"><img style="display: block !important; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;" border="0" src="01.jpg"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0 !important; line-height: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
            <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_parent" style="display: block !important;"><img style="display: block !important; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;" border="0" src="02.jpg"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0 !important; line-height: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
            <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_parent" style="display: block !important;"><img style="display: block !important; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;" border="0" src="03.jpg"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I actually think this depends on the version of the app on what OS, in Nougat it works a treat, in Marshmallow I get a line below the price, but I haven't seen what your seeing. You could try setting `border-collapse: collapse` on the images.

Comment: Might also be worth temporarily removing the anchor tags to see if you can identify if that might be causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to adjust the margins on the A tags..

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 650px !important; padding: 0 !important;">
    <tr style="padding: 0 !important;">
        <td style="padding: 0 !important; line-height: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
            <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_parent" style="display: block !important;"><img style="display: block !important; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;" border="0" src="https://d1ok0qgebci2d3.cloudfront.net/91/650x366/TheatricalsCos_EM_10112016_01.jpg"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0 !important; line-height: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
            <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_parent" style="display: block !important;margin-top:-4px"><img style="display: block !important; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;" border="0" src="https://d1ok0qgebci2d3.cloudfront.net/91/650x98/TheatricalsCos_EM_10112016_02.jpg"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0 !important; line-height: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
            <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_parent" style="display: block !important;margin-top:-4px"><img style="display: block !important; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;" border="0" src="https://d1ok0qgebci2d3.cloudfront.net/91/650x148/TheatricalsCos_EM_10112016_03.jpg"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```